# Kivy Transparent Canvas/Background

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to make my canvas/background transparent. Meaning if I put any buttons/labels or any other object on canvas ONLY THEY(labels/buttons...) will be visible while background is invisible. Best example would be making background invisible with label and button on it while background is invisible/see-through...

Example of Window.clearcolor not working :

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.dropdown import DropDown
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.core.window import Window

Builder.load_string('''

<ToggleButton>:
    on_state: app.root.on_state(self)

<MainScreen>:

    BoxLayout:

        ToggleButtons:


''')

class MainScreen(BoxLayout):
    Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 0, 0.5)

    def on_state(self, togglebutton):
        tb = togglebutton
        print(tb,tb.state,tb.text)


class ToggleButtons(Screen):

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(ToggleButtons,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        ResolutionsArray = ["1024x768", "1280x720", "1360x768", "1440x900", "1600x900", "1920x1080"]

        self.dropdown = DropDown()
        for index in ResolutionsArray:

            self.btn = Button(text=index, size_hint_y=None, height=44)

            self.btn.bind(on_release=lambda btn: self.dropdown.select(btn.text))

            self.dropdown.add_widget(self.btn)

        mainbutton = Button(text='1024x768',
                            border=(0, 0, 0, 0),
                            size_hint=(0.25, 0.15),
                            pos_hint={'x': .01, 'y': 0.1})

        mainbutton.bind(on_release=self.dropdown.open)
        
        self.dropdown.bind(on_select=lambda instance, x: setattr(mainbutton, 'text', x))

        self.add_widget(mainbutton)

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return MainScreen()


MyApp().run()
```

Comment: I don't think we support an api for this - it's technically possible at least to some extent on some platforms, but it requires some specific api calls around how the window is created. It isn't really much to do with the canvas api, the canvas is already transparent to the extent that this is possible, although you would likely need a transparent Window.clearcolor. We do have some shaped window support, maybe that works already.

Comment: I tried using `Window.clearcolor = (0, 0, 0, 0.1)`. And the 4th variable which should change the opacity does absolutely nothing for me. I can change RGB values and mess around with colors but opacity is always 100% no matter how early I call it